# " numWorkers " can not work ...How do I get it to work as intended?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When running DataFlow on GCP, DataFlow does not use the nodes specified in "numWorkers".
On the console, I can see that "TargetWorkers" is the same number as "numWorkers". but actual is not...
How do I get it to work as intended?

This is the command to deploy the template.

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=fqdn.of.main.Class \
         -Dexec.args=" \
           --project=my_gcp_project_name \
           --stagingLocation=gs://my_product/staging/  \
           --templateLocation=gs://my_product/template/Template \
           --runner=DataflowRunner  \
           --autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE \
           --numWorkers=90  \
           --workerMachineType=n1-highmem-4  \
           --enableStreamingEngine=true \
          "
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are specifying the flag "--autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE", you are also using  [Streaming Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine) which is a type of autoscaling.

I made a test using this [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven), when using Streaming Engine:

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
  -Dexec.args="--project=support-data-ez \
  --stagingLocation=gs://datacert/staging/ \
  --output=gs://datacert/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner  \
  --autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE \
  --numWorkers=90  \
  --workerMachineType=n1-highmem-4 
  --enableStreamingEngine=true \
  "
```

I have experimented with the same behavior.

[image]

You also have to verify that any quota has been reached.

[image]

When a quota is exceeded Dataflow will discard the flag "--numWorkers=90" and will determines an appropriate number of workers. So, consider this factor too.

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args="--project=support-data-ez \
      --stagingLocation=gs://datacert/staging/ \
      --output=gs://datacert/output \
      --runner=DataflowRunner  \
      --autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE \
      --numWorkers=58  \
      --workerMachineType=n1-standard-1
      --enableStreamingEngine=false \
```

[image]

As you can see when using a number of workers (or CPUs) that not exceed my quota and disabling the Streaming Engine feature I was able to use all the workers specified.

Comment: If Using Streaming engine, it will be auto scale. This is probably a bug, that not documented, but it has been greatly aided by your investigation. Thank you very much!

Comment: I made a deeper investigation and I figured out that when you enable Streaming Engine, there are two independent sets of machines: the Workers (just like in any Dataflow job, these are GCE machines), and the Windmill instances, which are processes running  on Google's infrastructure. Disabling autoscaling should, at the very least, keep the number of GCE workers constant. So this seems an issue with the autoscaling. So report the issue, it's a good idea.

Comment: Seems that the issue has been reported to the Dataflow Engineering team, you can follow the progress [here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/148400497)

Comment: The jobs where you tested are batch jobs?